# Can we solve a system of polynomial equations of one variable by finding GCD and solving it?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is following.
Suppose we have a system of $s$ polynomial equations of one variable $f_1, ..., f_s$. For $V(f_1,...f_s)$ I mean an affine variety - all points $x$ that satisfy all equations $f_i(x) = 0$. For $\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle$ I mean ideal of $f_1,...,f_s$.

I try to prove that $V(f_1,...,f_s) = V(\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle)$. If this is correct, it means that for a system of polynomial equations of a single variable we can find a greatest common divisor of that and solve just one equation, because $\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle = \langle gcd(f_1,...,f_s) \rangle$ and then $V(f_1,...,f_s) = V(\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle) = V(\langle gcd(f_1,...,f_s) \rangle)$.

And how it can be proved:

$\forall x \in V(f_1,...,f_s)$ and $\forall f \in \langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle$:

$f=\sum_{i=1}^s h_if_i\quad\Rightarrow \quad f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^sh_i(x)f_i(x)=0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad f \in V(\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle)$.

Thus, $V(f_1,...,f_s) \subset V(\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle)$.

Also, $\forall x \in V(\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle)$ and $\forall f \in \langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle : \ f(x) = 0$

But $f_1,...,f_s \in \langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle \quad \Rightarrow \quad \forall x \in V(\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle) \ \  f_1(x)=0,...,f_s(x)=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x \in V(f_1,...,f_s) \quad \Rightarrow \quad V(\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle) \subset V(f_1,...,f_s)$.

Thus $V(f_1,...,f_s)=V(\langle f_1,...,f_s \rangle) \ \square$

Haven't I missed something?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan
Great, thanks!